# MySQL query optimization: IN() vs OR

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I've been reading, that MySQL has a problem with queries that use IN() statement - sometimes indexes can't be used. Is that really so, if I don't use a subquery?

Which approach is better? Is there a performance difference?

## 1

```
SELECT *
FORM `somewhere`
WHERE 
  `id` = 3
   OR `id` = 5
   OR `id` = 15
   OR `id` = 56
   OR `id` = 34
   OR `id` = 47
```

## 2

```
SELECT *
FORM `somewhere`
WHERE 
  `id` IN (3,5,15,56,34,47)
```

Comment: I think that these are very similar in terms of performance. From what I understand when MySQL parses the IN() it translates it to ORs internally...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second approach is better. MySQL can optimize this.

> MySQL has a problem with queries that use IN() statement - sometimes indexes can't be used. Is that really so, if I don't use a subquery?

There can be a problem with IN when you write `IN(SELECT ...)`, but I don't think there is a problem with a simple list of values.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use indexes you can use UNION read more here [mysql-followup-on-union-for-query-optimization-query-profiling](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/14/mysql-followup-on-union-for-query-optimization-query-profiling/)